# Circular dependency in instantiating templates

Tags: c++, templates, types, circular-dependency

I want to build references between an `unordered_map` and a `map`. That is, the values of the `unordered_map` are iterators into the `map`, while the values of the `map` are iterators into the `unordered_map`. I think what I want to achieve is reasonable, yet failed to figure out how to instantiate the two templates.

A workaround is for the `map` to store keys into the `unordered_map`, but this is less efficient.

**Update:**

I intend to erase via the iterator, so `reference_wrapper` doesn't work here.

Comment: What about having a `map` and an `unordered_map` that both holds `std::reference_wrapper<T>` to the same object? Or store it in one, and have a reference_wrapper in the other.

Comment: @super I should be able to erase it. `reference_wrapper` doesn't serve this purpose.

Comment: You need to break the cycle with a forward declaration, which requires that you add an intermediary type of your own.

Comment: I retract my above suggestion -- now that I could test, neither `std::map` nor `std::unordered_map` accept incomplete types as values. Unfortunately I think that means that what you want is not feasible without some sort of type erasure such as `boost::any_iterator`.